# How to sum the values in a column conditioned by the values in another column?

Tags: r

I have two columns in a data frame, called `x` and `total`.
How can I calculate the sum of all cells in the `total` column where the value in `x` column is more than a specific number (let's say `Y`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, total=rnorm(10))
y <- 0.5
sum(df[df$x > y, "total"])
```

Comment: Thanks! but it is not working well. when I type 
sum(df["total"])
it gives the right total however when I add the conditions (x>y) the sum is not correct. 
just one thing the the values in x col star with 0 can this be the reason?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? E.g. `dput(head(yourData))`?

Comment: nbd(x(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,14,20,21,22)
nbd(total(34,12,45,78,66,54,78,85,34,22,13,45,12,17)

Comment: sorry, my bad I had a typo in my answer. I just corrected it.

Comment: it gives me this message on my data : In Ops.factor(nbd$x, 7) : > not meaningful for factors

Comment: Maybe have a look at some introductory material on R, where it talks about data types. You want `nbd$x` to be `nummeric`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be really nice if you added some examples, but I think this is what you want:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- 0.2

dat <-data.frame(x, total=cumsum(x))
xmorey <- dat$x > y

sum(dat$total[xmorey])
[1] 6.594804
```

Comment: it gives me this message on my data :
In Ops.factor(actfreqdis$x, 7) : > not meaningful for factors

Comment: apparently the problem is with the data type of my data frame but unfortunately I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: the above command shows that the column x in my dataset is factor. how can I convert it to num?

Comment: @AliTamaddoni `as.numeric(as.character(x))`